# Package pgf Error: No shape named is known. (D) edge node {a} (B) edge node {b} (E) ()

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto] 
\node[state,initial,accepting] (A)   {$A$}; 
\node[state,accepting] (B) [above right=of A] {$B$}; 
\node[state,accepting] (C) [above right=of B] {$C$}; 
\node[state,accepting](D) [below right=of C] {$D$} [loop above];
\node[state](E) [below left=of A] {$\emptyset$} [loop above];
\path[->] 
(A) edge  node {a} (B)
edge  node [swap] {b} (E)
(B) edge  node  {b} (C)
edge [loop above] node {a} ()
(C) edge  node  {a} (D) edge node [swap] {a}(B)
edge [loop above] node {b} ()

(E) edge [loop left] node {a,b}()
(D) edge node {a} (B) edge node {b} (E) ()            //this line is generating error?
;
////
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I am not getting why there is error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`edge node {b} (E) ()` is here interpreted as "place a node with the text `b`,  on the edge between the previous active coordinate and (E) then move to the coordinate `()`". There is no coordinate `()`, so you get an error. Just remove the last pair of empty parenthesis.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,automata}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto] 
\node[state,initial,accepting] (A)   {$A$}; 
\node[state,accepting] (B) [above right=of A] {$B$}; 
\node[state,accepting] (C) [above right=of B] {$C$}; 
\node[state,accepting](D) [below right=of C] {$D$} [loop above];
\node[state](E) [below left=of A] {$\emptyset$} [loop above];
\path[->]
(A) edge  node       {a} (B)
    edge  node[swap] {b} (E)
(B) edge  node[swap] {b} (C)
    edge [loop above] node {a} ()
(C) edge  node  {a} (D) 
    edge node [swap] {a}(B)
    edge [loop above] node {b} ()
(E) edge [loop left] node {a,b} ()
(D) edge node {a} (B) 
    edge node {b} (E);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Doesn't the the node name go before the text? At least that is always how I write it

Comment: @daleif On second thought I realize that my interpretation was wrong, updated my answer.

Comment: So they are actually interchangeable? Didn't know that

Comment: @daleif Damn, edited again. My previous edit wrong. The `(E)` belongs to the `edge`, so to speak.

Comment: Tricky one to read correctly